# How can I pass multiple parameters to a redux reducer with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters to a RTK reducer using useDispatch. Typically I would wrap the parameters in an object or array and destructure in the reducer. But I'm having a tough time doing this with Typescript, other than using my famous cheat code "any". I feel this is an extremely ignorant question and showcases my newness to Typescript, but would appreciate any help!

types:

- marker.id = string
- e.nativeEvent.coordinate = {latitude: number, longitude: number}

dispatch in my map component:

```js
dispatch(updateMarkerCoords([marker.id, e.nativeEvent.coordinate]))
```

rtk slice:

```js
    updateMarkerCoords: (state, action: PayloadAction<Array<any>>) => {
      const [id, coords] = action.payload
      const marker = state.addNewField.markers.find((m) => m.id === id)
      if (marker) {
        marker.coords = coords
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Redux Toolkit, generated action creators only accept *one* argument by default. If you want to pass in multiple values, you need to do so as an object.  And, the generic you provide to `PayloadAction` should define the fields and types in that object, such as:

```
updateMarkerCoords(state, action: PayloadAction<{id: string, coordinate: number}>) {
  // use action.payload.id and action.payload.coordinate here
}
```

If you really want to pass them in as separate parameters, you can write a "prepare callback" that converts them into the single `payload` field yourself:

```
updateMarkerCoordinate: {
  reducer(state, action: PayloadAction<{id: string, coordinate: number}>) {
    // same logic here
  },
  prepare(id: string, coordinate: number) {
    return {payload: {id, coordinate}}
  }
}
```

but most of the time it isn't worth it.

Comment: excellent, that felt like a workaround but glad to hear that it is an acceptable approach. Thanks for the help!